# Preventing the thumbnail in slider to slide once its selected

Tags: javascript, jssor

Is it possible to prevent the thumbnail images to prevent getting slided to first image in the ribbon and use navigator arrows alone to do the same? Currently, i could not find an API to achieve this. Help would be appreciated.

Current Behaviour: I click on the 3rd image in the thumbnail, then the 3rd image comes to the first image's position
Expected Behaviour: I click on the 3rd image in the thumbnail ribbon, the third image remains at the 3rd image position.

http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html

Thanks

Comment: are you refering to http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html

Comment: I should improve this feature, but there is no workaround to do this job at the moment.